# Mark all products as draft Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I currently have 9,000 products in my woocommerce store which are published and want to remove all of them without deleting them, is there a way to mark all 9,000 products as a draft without manually changing them to daft via bulk edit, as I can only modify 200-300 before I get a timeout error

Comment: Can you not increase the timeout settings on your server?

Comment: It might be simplest to modify the database directly. I don't know Woocommerce well enough to know if that's safe or possible though, e.g. if there's any extra workflow performed when you mark a product as draft over changing a status flag in the database.

Comment: @Chris I have tried but woocommerce still seems to become unresponsive/fails when trying to update more than a few hundred products

Comment: I know codecanyon have a bulk product editor plugin, but i'm not sure if that's any use . Failing that direct database editing would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'
```

**THIS WORKS PERFECTLY!**
@Thomas Brocken write "post_type = 'publish' but it is wrong:
**post_status** = 'publish"

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest just to do the following query on your wordpress database:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'draft' WHERE `post_type` = 'product' AND `post_type` = 'publish'
```

You could either use phpmyadmin if you have it or create a page template and use $wpdb to execute the query.

Comment: LAST "post_type = 'publish' IS WRONG.

"post_status = 'publish" IS RIGHT.

Comment: @thomas-broken please edit your response and I'll vote it up.

Comment: For publish to draft:

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'

For draft to publish:

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'publish' WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'draft'